# firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged wont work in expo

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

For some reason  1onAuthStateChange1 wont detect the logged in user in my physical device (samsung) using expo app. It always responds with "user  not logged in" Even though the user is visible in authentication user.

Current output: "User is not logged in",
Expected output: "User is " + user.phoneNumber,

Any help would be appreciated!

code:-

```
const checkUser = (dispatch) => {
  return () => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        console.log("User is " + user.phoneNumber);
        RootNavigation.navigate("home");
      } else {
        console.log("User is not logged in");

        RootNavigation.navigate("HomeRegistration");
      }
    });
  };
};
```

Comment: might want to add `async` ?

Comment: After your comment I did try it with async and await syntax, but the ide returns a warning of 'await' has no effect on the type of this expression. I checked other code snippets and most of them were similar to this.